# Scrapy spider is not collecting the first page of data and first item on each page may not be right either

Tags: python, scrapy

This spider pulls titles off the Funny subreddit pages.
I'm thinking the issue may be with the allowed url since the /funny home page doesn't match that.   If I add '/r/funny/'though to the allowed list, it will go wild and crawl too much.  Also, not sure what to make of the first item from each page being wrong (may be the last item on the previous page at times.

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http.response import Response

class Lesson1Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'lesson1'
    allowed_domains = ['www.reddit.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.reddit.com/r/funny/']

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            allow=['/r/funny/\?count=\d*&after=\w*',]),
            callback='parse_item',
            follow=True ),
    ]

    def parse_item (self, response):
        print(response.xpath('//p[@class="title"]/a/text()').extract())
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, it looks like your rule is contradicting your start url. The first page - `http://www.reddit.com/r/funny/` - doesn't have `/r/funny/\?count=\d*&after=\w*`, so it may be skipping it. Specifying a next page using the prev/next buttons at the bottom of each page may give you better results.

As for the second part, it may be that rankings are changing on reddit in between when you scrape and when you check, or that there's something in the source code (do any other `p` elements have the class title?) that you're not accounting for.

Comment: yes. i agree.  The rule is based on the next button at the bottom of the page.  Which I'm assuming is why the start page isn't being read (because it's not following the rule.   I guess I need an addition to the rule that says " accept the first page always and then go by the existing rule.

Comment: You can also just `yield` a new request for the next page, see the "Following links" section of the [Scrapy tutorial](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html).

Comment: (Also please accept this answer if it solved your problem)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I couldn't figure out the yield idea, but I did come up with another solution that I posted as a answer to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could find was to run two independent spiders in the same file.  One for the first page and one for pages 2 on.   This may not be the most efficient code, but being new, I'm happy all the components work.  Any suggestions on cleaning it up would be welcome.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http.response import Response
import csv
import sys

print("Which subreddit do you want to scrape?")
subreddit = sys.stdin.readline()
subreddit = subreddit.strip()

class Lesson1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "lesson1"
    allowed_domains = ['www.reddit.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.reddit.com/r/%s/' % subreddit]

    def parse(self, response):
        SET_SELECTOR = '//p[@class="title"]/a/text()'
        with open('redditscan8.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
            kelly = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect ='excel')

kelly.writerow(response.xpath('//p[@class="title"]/a/text()').extract())


class Lesson2Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'lesson1x'
    allowed_domains = ['www.reddit.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.reddit.com/r/%s/' % subreddit]

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            allow=['/r/%s/\?count=\d*&after=\w*' % subreddit, ]),
            callback='parse_item',
            follow=True),
    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        with open('redditscan8.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
            joe = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect ='excel')

joe.writerow(response.xpath('//p[@class="title"]/a/text()').extract())

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(Lesson1Spider)
process.crawl(Lesson2Spider)
process.start()
```

Comment: Check the [Scrapy tutorial](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) for how to yield a next page. The example they give: `next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)`